# Высокий уровень предупреждений и стандартные системные библиотеки/заголовки?

Tags: c++

Есть следующая проблема.

Для повышения качества кода в сборке проекта включается максимальный уровень предупреждений. В следствие этого появляется огромное количество предупреждений, которые указывают на возможные ошибки в стандартных системных библиотеках/заголовках.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у такой проблемы разумное решение?

Comment: А чем/как собираете? Для `cmake` есть решение `include_directories(SYSTEM ...)`, которое для `gcc` преобразуется в флаг `-isystem`.

Comment: Собираем `cmake`.

Comment: Как вариант - `#pragma warn` или какая там в вашем компиляторе для отключения предупреждений - вокруг системных заголовков. В VC++ я выставляю `/W4`, в общем-то, хороший компромисс...

Comment: @user207200, я не совсем понял, о чем вы говорите.

Comment: Ну при добавлении к проекту заголовочных файлов явно указывается, что они системные, это подавляет предупреждения.

Comment: @MGNeo, у `gcc` (и прочих подобных) есть флаг `-isystem`, который как раз и говорит компилятору продключать хедеры из этих каталогов, но не выводить для них предупреждения... в `cmake` он включается директивой `include_directories()` (и `target_include_directories()`) с указанием ключевого слова `SYSTEM`

Comment: ¿Может все-таки в нестандартных сторонних библиотеках? На стандартные и системные ругаться не должно и без всяких действий.

Comment: Ругается на стандартные Win-заголовки - winbase.h и пр.